# how to generate a token using keycloak url from angular without installing any JS library

Tags: angular

Want to generate a token using client_id,client_secret and client_credentials as grant type from angular without using any third party JS library.

I have this url of keycloak https://auth.mydomain.com/auth/realms/RealmName/protocol/openid-connect/token
and client_id,client_secret

Answer (score 0):

for this you dont need any third party library. Just import required dependency and do the following inside angular component or service

```
 import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

 appToken(){
  let params = new HttpParams();
  params = params.append("client_id","test.client").append("client_secret","pl7hdGLSVX3DekEqmmhiaaJarDana")
  .append("grant_type","client_credentials").append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');           
    var headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');    
    this.http
      .post('https://auth.mydomain.com/auth/realms/RealmName/protocol/openid-connect/token',
      params, {
          headers: headers
        })
        .subscribe(data => {                  
              this.accessToken = data;                 
        }, error => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
        });
}
```